# Dishwasher and disposal receptacle

Tags: electrical, kitchens

I have a single GFCI receptacle under my kitchen sink, and I want to power one end with constant power for the dishwasher and the other end with the switch leg from a switch on the backsplash for the disposal.  Can this be done?  I don't see the normal tab you can break on regular receptacles to do that on the GFCI.

Comment: You want to make half of a GFCI *receptacle* switched.  Is that correct?

Comment: What is this GFCI fed from?  A kitchen SABC, a lighting circuit, or a dedicated branch circuit?

Comment: Also, are you a person who believes firmly that a GFCI is a type of receptacle?  Or do you believe a GFCI is a protection device that comes in many forms, and one of them has a couple convenience outlets, and all of them can protect downline loads?  I'm not here to challenge anyone's beliefs but if you believe the latter, options open up.

Comment: I'm going to assume what this is: You have a switch, it powers a GFCI, the GFCI has a garbage disposal power feed in it (either plugged in, or wired in) and you have two outlets?  Just an FYI and I may be wrong, I believe if a dishwasher is permanently mounted, it is supposed to be hard wired. I also believe it is supposed to be on it's own circuit. hopefully someone up to speed on code will comment. But if your goal is to have both appliances GFCI'd, I would add romex to the switch box/outlet, and drive the GFCI unswitched, route the disposal to the switch.

Comment: Dishwashers do not need to be hardwired. Actually, if you have had a dishwasher installed recently (by a Loews or HD installer), they will refuse to install a dishwasher if the current one is hardwired. They are not ‘electricians certified’ so can only ‘plug/unplug’ the electrical, hence this rule for them. Converting to a plug is generally an easy DIY for many home handyman types. Look it up on YouTube. Costs about $20 and takes about an hour!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot split a GFCI receptacle, however, a GFCI receptacle is not the only way to provide GFCI protection to a circuit.

## GFCI Circuit Breaker

One option, would be to provide GFCI protection to the entire circuit by installing a GFCI circuit breaker.  Install a 20 ampere GFCI circuit breaker, and run 12 AWG copper conductors to the receptacle location.  Then you'll simply wire a standard receptacle, in a half switched configuration.

## Blank Face GFCI Device

Another option, is to use a blank face (dead front) GFCI device to provide protection.

- Install a double wide box at the receptacle location.
- Connect the wires feeding into the box to the LINE terminals on the GFCI device.
- Use the LOAD terminals on the device to feed a standard receptacle, wired in a half switched configuration.